# Can we migrate questions to StackOverflow / CS.SE?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, migration

First, I realise that this question is a [duplicate](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/385/12205), but since that was asked a long time ago, I think it would be appropriate to ask it again.

**Edit**: Some questions may be a better fit for the [Computer Science Stack Exchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com), so I have included this in the title as well.

Recently, we have a lot (in my opinion) of "general programming questions"

- https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/23157/12205
- [a question about getline in C++!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/23114/12205) (Deleted)
- [How to find the maximum in any interval in an array with preprocessing in O(nlogn)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/23006/12205) (Deleted)
- [On pop up accordian is called in that i want to display error message](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/22948/12205) (Deleted)
- https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/22809/12205
- https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/22665/12205
- [Operations on stacks of coins](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/22653/12205) (Deleted)

Edit:

- https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/23427/12205

That is seven questions over five days, or an average of 1.4 question per day, that I think should belong to StackOverflow question instead.

The answer on the linked question states that

> If you want a migration path to a site, you'll need to provide ample evidence that you actually have a sufficient demand for it. **You need a significant number of questions that you either have already migrated to Stack Overflow, or are valid migrations to Stack Overflow that have yet to be addressed.**

In my opinion this is a significant number, so I'm thinking whether we should have migration to StackOverflow. From the askers' perspective, I think it would help them a lot if their question can be migrated automatically, instead of being criticized here. From our perspective, it could clear up the site (without so many [on hold] questions) and we don't need to repeat the comment -> vote to close -> vote to delete procedure.

<s>Related: Looking at [this page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/away) in the moderator tools, I realised that there were some migrations to StackOverflow in 2011 and early 2012. Since I am relatively new here, was there some historical reasons that caused the migration link to be removed?</s>

P.S. first meta question, so I'm not sure whether I got the tags right.

Comment: Re related: Mods can migrate to any site.

Comment: There was never a migration link: those were migrated by mods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Roughly 40-45% of the off-topic questions I've seen lately would be a better fit for CS.SE than for SO, with another 40-45% being good for SO. I think an open channel to both sites would enable us to serve the askers with less friction than they currently get from us.

As for the remaining off-topic questions, there is just nothing you can do with some of them but delete (e.g. tattoo guy), but it would be nice to be able to help the rest, who have often just accidentally posted here because they're green or disoriented.

Comment: "Tattoo guy"? I must've missed something...

Comment: @Riking Someone offered to pay for some code to use as a tattoo. Bizzare.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the (very) late answer

[This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91446/400441) summarizes it all.

I don't know what the situation was back in 2014, but we receive questions that would be deemed too unclear by Stack Overflow (aka the trash questions they already receive).

It may be on-topic for Stack Overflow, but as Jeff Atwood said, "Don't. Migrate. Crap."

Comment: We need, firstly, a VTC that allows us to select which SE we think a question might be better suited for, rather than just SO alone and, secondly, a VTC that says a question does not belong on SE at all.

Comment: @Shaggy Okay. I don't object nor support that decision because I am too inexperienced on PPCG to decide

Comment: To provide some small context: there have been many questions in my 2 years here that haven't belonged here and nor have they belonged on SO. They have, however, been suited to other SE's (e.g., Maths, CS, CR, Puzzling, etc.). There have also been questions so bad that they would be poorly received no matter which SE they were posted to. But the only VTC option we have is to suggest SO. ([Here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/186312/58974)'s a prime example of a question that doesn't fit anywhere on SE but, because it's the only option available, Hyper's VTCed it as belonging on SO)

Comment: @Shaggy Okay, I see

Comment: @Shaggy, there are two factual errors in your comments above. Firstly, the site-customised close text doesn't say that the question belongs on SO, but that the *questioner* *might* be able to get help on SO. Secondly, there is a textarea if close voters want to write a custom explanation pointing at other sites in the network. But all this is only marginally related to this meta-question anyway, which is about closing with automatic migration (currently only offered between main and meta).